# how to inherit from generic repository without needing to implement all the members

Tags: c#

Im trying to create a generic repository ,here is my IGenericRepository:

```
 public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
     Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindByFilterAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] including);
     Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id);
     Task<bool> InsertAsync(TEntity obj);
}
```

here is the implementation of the respository:

```
 public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;
    public GenericRepository(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory) => this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindByFilterAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] including)
    {
        using (var scope = this.scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CleanArchitectureContext>();
            var x = db.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
            if (including != null)
            {
                including.ToList().ForEach(s =>
                {
                    if (s != null)
                    {
                        x = x.Include(s);
                    }
                });
            }

            return await x.Where(predicate).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
        }

    }

    public Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<bool> InsertAsync(TEntity obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

now lets say i need to have an interface which is going to inherit from the IGeneric repository and store data in the db:

```
 public interface IStorePayoutRepository:IGenericRepository<PayoutModel>
{
   
}
```

so far so good, the problem is if i want to have a class and inherit from IStorePayoutRepository,then i need to implement all the members inside that which is not what i want,because i need only the store one(save or insert into db),

```
  public class PayoutRepository : IGenericRepository<PayoutEntity>
            {
              //Im forced to implement all the members inside generic interface
            }
```

as you see its not very optimal to implement all the members everytime as they could be irrelevant to the usecase,whats the right way here?i appreciate your help

Comment: That's what interfaces do. They force you to abide by the contract they dictate. If you don't want classes to implement the contract's members, don't put it in the interface.

Comment: @gunr2171thanks but is that really what generic repository does? We have to implement all the members every time?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from splitting this into multiple interfaces that can be implemented independently, or indeed when split into three methods nothing prevents you from directly passing those as delegates, instead of a separate interface. Alternatively, you can provide an `AbstractRepository` base class that implements the repository with `NotImplementedException` for all but the "essential" methods, and deriving from that rather than implementing the interface directly.